# Unique serial ID over all subtypes

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, ddl

I have the following problem with designing a database:
In my EER-diagram I have the supertype Entity A with 2 subtype entities B and C.

The table-schemas look like this:

```
Create table A {
     attributes of A here,
     ID int
}

Create table B {
     attributes of B here,
    ID int SERIAL
}

Create table C {
     attributes of C here,
    ID int SERIAL
```

ID in table B and C refer to table A to maintain the supertype-relation.
I have a list of data which contains all attributes except for the ID which I have to make on my own while reading in the data (using the "create table as"-statement).
I have this problem: When I read in the data, the ID attributes of B and C all start counting from 1 to ... .
Thought I want the ID's of B and C to be different.

I tried putting the "SERIAL"-keyword in table A, but then is my question: How can I get that ID to B or C?

Comment: I added the postgres tag because of the use of serial.  You should tag your questions with the database you are actually using.

Comment: You could always have foreign keys in B and C that refer to A.

Comment: Use a single sequence for all id columns

Answer (score 2):

use inheritance instead one to many relation?

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html

or you can just use the same sequence in both tables

```
CREATE SEQUENCE A_seq;
CREATE TABLE B (
   id INT NOT null DEFAULT nextval('A_seq'::regclass) PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE C (
   id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('A_seq'::regclass) PRIMARY KEY
)
```

Comment: I searched everywhere , but I didn't find anything about sequences. That did the trick. Thank you for your answer, sir.